# Theme related issue

Tags: snow-leopard, themes

The attached image(s) should be a visual reference to what I am attempting to verbalize. My issue is that last summer I was playing with theme management on OS X 10.6.x and all was well but lately programs like luxrender & virtualbox show up with clear/transparent backdrops and viewing the dialog boxes is difficult sometimes impossible. I'm wondering if anyone is aware of the file(s) I might need to replace/alter to correct this issue as a reinstall seems a bit heavy handed to rectify this situation... (When viewing the image(s) please note that when I view the actual program my desktop or whatever is behind the window bleeds through) Any and all help with this matter would be welcomed & appreciated!

(ANNOTATION: images aren't allowed by new users so please ignore references)

Comment: Can you please post a link to the images?

Answer (score 1):

If the theming's the cause of your problem you'll probably need to replace :

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Resources/SArtFile.bin
```

That's the file associated with visual styles on OS X. Hope you had a backup !